# "Thank you for your consideration" am Ende eines Bewerbungsschreibens

Tags: usage, phrase, idiom, formality, letter

So könnte das Ende eines englischen Bewerbungsschreibens aussehen:

> Thank you for your consideration.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> John Doe

Auf deutsch fällt mir nur ein

> Mit freundlichen Grüßen,
>
> Max Mustermann

Wie sagt man das?

`Thank you for your consideration` klingt wie `Danke, dass sie mir eine ehrliche Chance geben und ernsthaft darueber nachdenken was ich gesagt habe`.

`Vielen Dank für Ihre Zeit` klingt irgendwie schwach, wie `Thank you, your highness, for having the mercy to ready my unworthy letter` als sei meine Bewerbung es kaum würdig eine Minute daran zu verbringen, vor allem nicht für den Leser.

`Danke fuer Ihre Bemühungen` klingt als würde ich eine Anfrage an den Kundenservice schicken `Könnten sie mir eine neue Fernbedienung zu meinem Fernseher schicken? Die alte funtkioniert nicht mehr. Danke für Ihre Bemühungen.`

Aber das ist natürlich alles nur mein subjektives Sprachverständnis.  Was sollte ich schreiben?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In der Regel drückt man am Ende eines deutschen Bewerbungsschreibens die Erwartung oder Hoffnung auf eine Einladung zu einem Vorstellungsgespräch aus:

> Ich würde mich freuen, Sie in einem persönlichen Gespräch von meinen Fähigkeiten überzeugen zu können.

Mit den Stichwörten "Bewerbungsschreiben Schlußsatz" findest Du bei der Suchmaschine Deiner Wahl eine ganze Reihe von Ratgebern und Formulierungsvorschlägen. Ich würde Dir aber empfehlen, wenn irgend möglich einen Muttersprachler mit Bewerbungserfahrung zu Rate zu ziehen, der beurteilen kann, ob der Schlußsatz zum Rest des Schreibens und zur Stellenanzeige paßt.

Comment: Danke fuer die gute Antwort! Ich muss lachen wegen deiner Empfehlung... In der momentanen Situation bin ich der zur Rate gezogene Muttersprachler... *lol* Aber Bewerbungserfahrung in deutsch hab ich halt kaum, und ich konnte mich einfach nicht erinnern, wie man das sagt. ^_^

Comment: Danke für das Feedback - freut mich, daß ich helfen konnte!  - Nette Überraschung ;-) Die Referenz auf das englische Beispiel hatte in mir sofort das Bild eines englischen Muttersprachlers erzeugt.